# What does it mean for phase lines to be qualitatively the same?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following phase lines for a differential equation
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y^{2}+a$$
[image]

And it was mentioned that the phase lines for $a < 0$ are qualitatively the same, and the phase lines for $a > 0$ are qualitatively the same. However, I feel confused. What does it mean for phase lines to be qualitatively the same? And why isn't $a=0$ considered to be qualitatively the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they mean is that the picture for any negative value of $a$ looks essentially the same as the picture for any other negative value of $a$: two equilibrium values (the solid dots), arrows going up below the lower one and above the upper one, arrow going down between the two dots.
And the picture for any positive value of $a$ looks the same as  the picture for any other positive value of $a$: no equilibrium, the arrow goes up.

As for $a=0$, there isn't any other value for that to be the same as (one equilibrium, arrows up on both sides).

Answer (score 1):

An answers with actual formula transformations is possible here. If you consider $$y(t)=cu(ct)$$ for some fixed parameter $c=\sqrt{|a|}$ (for $a\ne 0$), then $$y'(t)=c^2u'(ct)$$ on the one hand and $$y(t)^2+a=c^2u(ct)^2+a$$ on the other. So for $a>0$ the equation cancels to a normal form $$u'=u^2+1,$$ for $a<0$ it cancels to a normal form $$u'=u^2-1$$ and $a=0$ is a special case that requires no transformation to a normal form.